# Magento 2 Custom REST API Json response

Tags: magento2.3.0, magento2-api

I have developed my custom rest API endpoint. Here is the code

**webapi.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
<route method="POST" url="/V1/createcustomorder">
    <service class="Demo\CreateOrderApi\Api\CreateCustomOrderManagementInterface" method="postCreateCustomOrder"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="Magento_Sales::create"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Demo\CreateOrderApi\Api\CreateCustomOrderManagementInterface" type="Demo\CreateOrderApi\Model\CreateCustomOrderManagement"/>
</config>
```

**Api/CreateCustomOrderManagementInterface.php**

```
<?php
namespace Demo\CreateOrderApi\Api;

interface CreateCustomOrderManagementInterface
{

/**
 *
 *
 * @param array $orderData[]
 * @return mixed[]
 *
 *
 */
public function postCreateCustomOrder();
}
```

**Model/CreateCustomOrderManagement.php**

```
 <?php
 namespace Demo\CreateOrderApi\Model;

  class CreateCustomOrderManagement implements \Demo\CreateOrderApi\Api\CreateCustomOrderManagementInterface
  {

   /**
   * @return mixed[]
   */
   public function postCreateCustomOrder()
   {
     /**
     --rest of code--
     **/

     $this->response[]['dsal'] = ['estatus' => ['0' => ['codigo' => 400, 'mensaje' => 'my message']]];

   return $this->response;
   }

  }
```

In my rest client, I'm expecting output like this

```
 {
    "dsal": {
        "estatus": [
            {
                "codigo": 400,
                "mensaje": "No such entity with customerId = 12"
            }
        ]
    }
 }
```

but Magento gives me output with extra braces

```
[
 {
    "dsal": {
        "estatus": [
            {
                "codigo": 400,
                "mensaje": "No such entity with customerId = 12"
            }
        ]
    }
 }

]
```

Can anybody tell me what wrong with return type and return array in my code?

Comment: try putting parenthesis be estatus like this **$this->response[]['dsal'] =( ['estatus' => ['0' => ['codigo' => 400, 'mensaje' => 'my message']]]);**

Comment: try this **$res = $this->response; print_r(json_encode($res));**

Comment: @magefms $res = $this->response;


                return print_r(json_encode($res)); seems working but is this correct way to return?

Comment: yeah it's the same , you just encode the return value into json format using json_encode.

Comment: @magefms I'm finding another solution as print_r should not be used in return. This is not a standard way

Comment: ah okay maybe try direct encoding

Comment: this one ` $res = $this->response; return json_encode($res);` doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and finally I did this:

```
<?php
 namespace Demo\CreateOrderApi\Model;

  class CreateCustomOrderManagement implements \Demo\CreateOrderApi\Api\CreateCustomOrderManagementInterface
  {

   /**
   * @return mixed[]
   */
   public function postCreateCustomOrder()
   {
     /**
     --rest of code--
     **/
       header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
       $this->response = json_encode($responseArray);
       print_r($this->response,false);
       die();
   }
  }
```

It is not the best solution but it's the only way it works.

Comment: I am getting an error "Undefined variable responseArray" while trying the above solution, could you plz suggest where I should declare $responseArray

Answer (score 1):

This question pops up quite a bit but I've find no complete answer so far, so here goes:

Using [this guide's example](https://alankent.me/2015/07/24/creating-a-new-rest-web-service-in-magento-2/) (Example 3: Mid-point Between two Points), you basically need to add two more things in order to return a simple JSON via REST API:

1. a data structure interface (**PointInterface.php** in the guide) that has setters and getters for the properties you wish to include in the JSON. This interface is used as a return type annotation in the REST service contract (**CalculatorInterface.php**)
2. a model that implements the above mentioned data structure interface (**Point.php**), which basically has private properties for the properties you wish to include in the JSON, and implements some basic setters/getters on them

After implementing 1) and 2), all that's left is to use a factory to create the new model, set its properties and just return it in the REST API method (no json_encode, print_r, etc required) as seen here in the **Calculator.php** class:

```
/**
 * Compute mid-point between two points.
 *
 * @api
 * @param PointInterface $point1 The first point.
 * @param PointInterface $point2 The second point.
 * @return PointInterface The mid-point.
 */
public function midPoint($point1, $point2) {
    $point = $this->pointFactory->create();
    $point->setX(($point1->getX() + $point2->getX()) / 2.0);
    $point->setY(($point1->getY() + $point2->getY()) / 2.0);
    return $point;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     <?php
 namespace Demo\CreateOrderApi\Model;

  class CreateCustomOrderManagement implements \Demo\CreateOrderApi\Api\CreateCustomOrderManagementInterface
  {

   /**
   * @return mixed[]
   */
   public function postCreateCustomOrder()
   {
     /**
     --rest of code--
     **/

     $this->response['dsal'] = ['estatus' => ['0' => ['codigo' => 400, 'mensaje' => 'my message']]];

   return $this->response;
   }

  }
```

Comment: this will truncate dsal node and give ouput like [
    {
        "estatus": [
            {
                "codigo": 400,
                "mensaje": "my message"
            }
        ]
    }
]

Comment: return $this->response[0];

Comment: found the problem?

Comment: Not yet $this->response[0]; not working

Comment: $this->response = ['dsal' => ['estatus' => ['0' => ['codigo' => 400, 'mensaje' => 'my message']]]];

Comment: I thought you need to change annotation comment from return mixed[] to return string[]